# Chrome debugger / breakpoint stops at wrong line

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

It's been from version 0.47 that my breakpoints in chrome developer tool, would technically stops at the right line but it's shown otherwise on the source code panel.
there would always be a 1 or 2 line shift between the actual breakpoint and the blue colored selected line. that makes it very difficult to debug as it's never shown right, does anyone heard of a solution?

```
if(true){
  this.anyfunction();
  debugger;
  var toto = 10;
  toto ++;
}
```

In this example the first selected blue line in source code would be toto++, while toto would be undefined if you'd add a watch on toto, that's why I assume the breakpoint is properly hit, but there's a display problem...

Comment: So you set your breakpoint on `debugger`, but DevTools highlights `toto++` blue, and when you set a watch expression on `toto`, it's undefined?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of this?

Comment: yes, it's exactly that, for security reasons (I m at work) I can't upload anything, but I ll try from home.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same problem, It's working fine after I change inspect tools settings in chrome..

1. Click three dot icon in right top corner of inspect tool and select **Settings**.
   (or)
   Click F1.
2. Uncheck the **Enable JavaScript source maps** checkbox under the Sources in Preferences.
3. Now it's working fine...

Comment: hi, I do use javascript source maps. latest versions of chrome don't have the problem anymore though.

Answer (score 0):

Is your expression spread across multiples lines? For example:

```
var x = 1 +
        2 +
        3 +
        4 +
        5;
```

This is known to cause wonky behavior. When I set the breakpoint on the 1st line and then run the script, DevTools pauses on the 4th line.

Solution: set the breakpoint on the line above the expression.

Comment: No, it's not even a spread line, it happens no matter where I put my break point in the code....

Answer (score 0):

- in "chrome developer tools"
- in "source" tab
- look for 'cr' text in RED
  color!

if you find anything it's mean there is some ENTER at the end of some lines that is not compatilble with you current EOF setting.
replace 'cr' with ENTER and you should good to go

> EOF: End-Of-Line

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the Enable JavaScript source maps